# отправка письма с файлом на python + jquery

Tags: html, python, jquery, flask

Есть код отправки писем на `python` с одной почты на другую через `smtplib`. Кроме самих писем, мне нужно отправлять еще и приложение(картинку например). Я могу загружать и видеть любую загруженную картинку через `jquery`. Вопрос:

Как передать ее во Flask, чтобы ее тоже отправлять?

`python`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
 
msg = MIMEMultipart()

password = "your_password"
msg['From'] = "your_address"
msg['To'] = "to_address"
msg['Subject'] = "Photos"
 
msg.attach(MIMEImage(file("google.jpg").read()))
 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()
server.login(msg['From'], password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To'])

return render_template('upload.html')
```

`upload.html`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type='file' class="form-control" id="imgInp" style="width: 80%;">
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="" style="width: 20%; height: 20%; margin-left: 10px;">

<script>
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
}); 
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение таково. Нужно добавить `MIMEApplication`

```
file = request.form['file']
file_to_send = MIMEApplication(open(file, 'rb').read())
file_to_send.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
msg.attach(file_to_send)
```